# Android Studio Generate EditText dynamically at a specific location

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to generate EditText below my TextView and Above my Button (see image below).
I am using linear layout for this.

I already can generate my EditText in java using this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_procedure);

    LinearLayout L = findViewById(R.id.container);
    EditText E = new EditText(this);
    L.addView(E);
}
```

[image]

But when I run this the element displays below my button which makes sense since I didn't told it where to display exactly right?

Is there any way I can display this element above the Button and below the TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible to specify index while dynamically adding a view to a LinearLayout.**

```
LinearLayout.addView(childView, index);     
                 //index = position where you want to insert the new view.
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.layout.activity_create_procedure` likely is a `LinearLayout` (which affects the positioning). Better add the `TextView` into the XML aready with `android:visibility="gone"` set and then change it's visibility (having set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` causes it to fade in).